# Alfresco REST api 'groups/children?level="ALL"', does something similar exist?

Tags: java, rest, alfresco

Calling alfresco's webscripts using the REST api as described on the alfresco wiki [here](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/3.2_REST_API_Group_Service), I can call for all groups, their explicit children, parents, and even implicit parents using the GET parameter `level` with value `"ALL"`. It happens I need the implicit children rather than parents, but can't find a similar method for it. Does it, or an alternative using the same techniques, exist? If not, why not?

My dev environment for this project is GWT/GXT in combination with Alfresco share accessed using OpenCMIS and the alfresco REST api.

**Conclusion:**

exists:

```
/services/api/groups/<groupname>/parents?level="ALL"
```

I need:

```
/services/api/groups/<groupname>/children?level="ALL"
```

Or similar functionality.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about why `/services/api/groups/<groupname>/children` isn't enough?

Comment: As stated, it gives me the explicit children, like using parents without the level GET parameter gives me explicit parents only, while I want the implicit children too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is a REST API to return all users of an Authority including indirect members, there's just the direct members call.

However, the [underlying Java service does support this](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/service/cmr/security/AuthorityService.html#getContainedAuthorities%28org.alfresco.service.cmr.security.AuthorityType,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) - just set the `immediate` flag to false. If you really need this, it'd be pretty quick to knock up a new webscript to expose this. (It'll need to be a Java backed webscript, as it doesn't look like ScriptGroup or ScriptAuthorityService expose that)

Comment: To keep the implementation process as easy as possible, we're trying hard to avoid the use of things like extra webscripts. Despite not being the solution I am looking for, definitely a great answer to the question!

Answer (score 2):

`/api/groups/<groupname>/children`

This will give you the immediate children of the group. I don't believe there is a REST API to recursively retrieve all children of a group - you would need to make several calls.

Comment: What I currently do, But it hardly seems optimal. Thanks for the input!